How to create a working .apk file from old code?
Around 2021/2022 I uploaded 2 apps (kivy==2.0.0, kivymd==0.104.1, buildozer==1.3.0) on Google Play . Now I have to change API level from 30 to 33. I really don’t want to change the code at the moment. I only want to create a new .apk file with higher API level.
My problem:

First I tried to create a package with buildozer v1.5.0. I was able to create an .apk file but when I installed it on my phone and on Android Studio, it crashed. So I thought my old code doesn’t compatible with new buildozer and dependencies.

So next time I tried with buildozer v1.3.0. Unfortunately I’m not able to create an .apk file. I always get an error. I solved some but I still get some...


How I tried to create an .apk file (buildozer==1.3.0):

VirtualMachine

Lubuntu 22.04.3

Dependencies I install on new system:

sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python3-openssl git
sudo apt install libedit-dev
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer.git --branch 1.3.0
sudo apt-get install -y python3-setuptools
cd buildozer
sudo python3 setup.py install
cd ..
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-11-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev libssl-dev
pip3 install Cython
pip3 install --user --upgrade Cython==0.29.19 virtualenv
sudo apt-get install cython
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >>~/.bashrc


At the first attempt buildozer fails to create a package because the ndk-r25b link is changed so I have to manually download it (https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r25b-linux.zip) and paste it to „.buildozer/android/platform”.

But after this I get this error (I even tried to change Cython version):
-
STDOUT:
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
1 warning
running build_ext
building 'jnius' extension
/home/pc/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -I/home/pc/Desktop/dict/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include -DANDROID -I/home/pc/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include -I/home/pc/Desktop/dict/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/mydict/armeabi-v7a/include/python3.1 -fPIC -I/home/pc/Desktop/dict/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Include -I/home/pc/Desktop/dict/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build -c jnius/jnius.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/jnius/jnius.o
jnius/jnius.c:196:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
#include "longintrepr.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command '/home/pc/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1


Could you help me? What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to create an .apk file from old codes with old release of buildozer?
